# Why php session var that is set has been lost after redirect by javascript

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter, session

I have two page that are skytrip.localhost/searchresults and skytrip.localhost/bookingInfo

In page searchresults  , I make  ajax request  , then  it is redirected to page bookingInfo. In ajax request , I set  a sesion value , then I want to get this value  in the page bookingInfo. But I can't get this value. When I dump $_SESSION , I  see that this value is not set  and session var that belongs to this value doesn't exist , but other previous session values  has been seen.

Ajax request call php code and set value to session

```
 $session->set(Fly_Constant::SESSION_BOOK_PRICE_VERIFIED_SOLUTION_PARAMETER, "yunuz");
```

After response , redirect to page bookingInfo

```
window.location.href = PageInitialData.BASE_URL +"bookingInfo";
```

I try to get  this value

```
$bookPriceVerifyResponse = $session->get(Fly_Constant::SESSION_BOOK_PRICE_VERIFIED_SOLUTION_PARAMETER,1800);
```

Comment: what CI version are you using?

Comment: I don't know about CI3 but about CI2.x the session is buggy and not secured (it uses cookies to save session data) so I use this session extension instead and it does a good job https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/wiki/EckoSession hope that helps

Comment: I dont use codeigniter session. I use $_SESSION in my session helper

Comment: then if  you show us the session helper that may help

Comment: Very thanks for your interesting. The problem is not session helper.   while  I see  previoust session values , I can't see   session var / value that set lastest before redirect.    While I see this value  in $_SESSION before redirecting ,  after redirect ,   I can't see  this value in  $_SESSION.

Comment: _Check_ if the session id is passed correctly with each of the requests you are making.

Comment: I have checked  , PHPSESSIONID values are same :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't use framework session mechanism, please ensure that you have session_start() call before using $_SESSION, otherwise this data will be lost.

Comment: Very thanks for your interesting.  while I see previoust session values , I can't see session var / value that set lastest before redirect. While I see this value in $_SESSION before redirecting , after redirect , I can't see this value in $_SESSION.

Comment: Just try the answer and you'll see. You need the call to session_start() to make PHP load and save session information between pages. Without it, S_SESSION will be gone as soon as the script ends.

Comment: Yes , I find the problem.   the problem is that I call session_start if $_SESSION is not setted. but  I have called session_write_close in other function  before setting this value to session. In this case , the session is not exists and $_SESSION is not empy.  because of session not exists , this problem occurs. To solve this problem  ,  I call session_start()  when session_status() !== PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE.

Answer (score 0):

Try full URL and relative url in your redirections, if I remeber correctly that affects SESSION too.